# Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'response.profileObj'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I faced with a problem while I was coding about Google sign-in line. I wrote these lines:

```
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profileObj))

    const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;

    const doc = {
      _id: response.profileObj.googleId,
      _type: 'user',
      userName: response.profileObj.name,
      image: response.profileObj.imageUrl,
    }

    client.createIfNotExists(doc)
      .then(() => {
        navigate('/', { replace: true })
      });
  }
```

But when I am looking through console log, I see there is appearing

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of
> 'response.profileObj' as it is undefined.

So what kind of solutions do you offer for me? Btw also these code should direct me to the main page after log in with my email but it also doesn't work.

Comment: add a null check for `response.profileObj` then do rest of the operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a null check like this.

```
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));
    if (response.profileObj) {
      const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;

      const doc = {
        _id: response.profileObj.googleId,
        _type: "user",
        userName: response.profileObj.name,
        image: response.profileObj.imageUrl,
      };

      client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
        navigate("/", { replace: true });
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Else if you provide type of the profileObj it wont throw that error

Comment: Yes! You solved it. Thank you so much! Actually, it should be direct me to main page but it doesnt for now but "name" issue gone!

Answer (score 0):

Your `response.profileObj` seems to be undefined
Are you sure you passed the `profileObj` property in the `response` object?